# is it reasonable to use defmethod instead of defun even though there is no direct link between the class and the function/method

Tags: oop, coding-style, common-lisp

Consider this example:

> There is a class named 'first', which is defined in package 'a'.
>
> There is also a package 'b' which uses module 'a' functionalities.
>   Certain functions of package 'b' would require a object of class
>   'first' as a parameter. But besides this, there is no direct logical
>   link between package 'a' and 'b'.

Now I wonder if it would be reasonable to write `(defmethod package-b-function ((param first)) #|do stuff..|#)` instead of a normal function, as the function needs the object and defining a method would clarify this for both the runtime environment and other users of package 'b'.

I used to program in C++/Java therefore I am not familiar with the OOP conventions to be used in this case.

Appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Methods in Common Lisp don't quite work the same way as the languages you note (see the [appropriate](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) two [chapters](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html) of [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) for details). In a nutshell, at a very high level, you need to think about OO in lisp as "methods specialize on classes" rather than "classes have methods".

That said, yes, I think it would be perfectly reasonable for a package to have a method specializing on a class that's defined elsewhere. Specifying the type of input you're expecting clarifies intent for future readers (and may or may not help in optimization, but that's not terribly important from my perspective). If you're [defining an ASDF system](http://common-lisp.net/~mmommer/asdf-howto.shtml#sec6) for your package, make sure to `import` the appropriate symbol, and `depends-on` the appropriate package.

Just as a footnote, be aware that Common Lisp isn't particularly object oriented as a language (for example, you'll run into some odd corners if you decide that a particular class should have `length`, `pop` or `push` methods, or specialize on arithmetic operations).

Comment: You don't necessarily have to import the symbol to use this technique. (defmethod package-b-function ((param a::first)) #|do stuff..|#) works just fine too.

Comment: You can also do (defmethod a::method ((param symbol-in-b))); depending on if you want generic functions in each package, or only a single generic function. I know this isn't directly related to your question, but just wanted to provide a bit more info on how CLOS dispatch can work when using multiple packages.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp provides ordinary functions and generic functions.

As a first rule use this:

Use generic functions when you want to assemble the effective method from various available methods (for example when programming with Mixins) or when you want to select a method based on runtime arguments.

If you don't need this advanced behavior, then just use ordinary functions. Documenting what kind of arguments an ordinary function needs and corresponding runtime checks can be done with other CL functionality:

- `CHECK-TYPE`
- `ASSERT`
- Documentation strings
- `DECLARE` argument types

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, both a function and a method work fine from a purely technical POV in the scenario you describe.  Inaimathi's answer (and the text of your question) give reasons why to use `defmethod` (better communication of intent to the reader, better compiler information).  One reason to use a plain function instead is to aid in refactoring, both in the early stages of design and in exploratory programming.  A common CL technique is for functions to accept any argument that is only passed through to other functions (e.g., in your case, accessors that get / set slots of `a:first` within `package-b-function`).

If you make `package-b-function` a function, you can change the name of class `a:first`, change it from a class to a structure to an alist to a vector and back while doing performance measurements, and your intermediate `package-b-function` and its 50 brothers will just keep on working.  If you encode type information using `defmethod`, the price you pay is that you have to change lots of code when you change fundamental data structures in your system, so you cannot easily answer questions like "would the thing run faster if I used 5-element vectors instead of objects here?"  Otherwise, it's just a matter of defining the 5 accessor functions to do `svref` instead of `slot-value` and the factory to call `vector` instead of `make-instance`.